# Algebraically Deriving a function from a Table of Values

Tags: functions

Is there an algebraic solution to deriving a function from a table of values, for example:
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
x &f(x) \\
\hline
1 &2 \\
\hline
2 &4 \\
\hline
\end{array}

which produces $f(x)=2x$

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
x &f(x) \\
\hline
1 &1 \\
\hline
2 &4 \\
\hline
3 &9 \\
\hline
\end{array}

which produces $f(x)=x^2$

How can this be derived algebraically? And what will result if you are given a table of values that does not represent a function? Is it possible to find a table of values that is similar that will result in a function?

**Context:** *I'm writing software that interprets an image and finds it's outline, then converts the outline to a set of polynomials that when drawn, create an outline similar within a degree of the original images outline*

Comment: You can't derive a single function from a table of values if you don't have the whole values of that functions, since there are infinitely many functions which satisfy $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=4$.

Comment: Given any such table there are infinite polynomials which agree with the tables. See for instance [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Is there a _best_ fit polynomial? What is the mathematical concept behind finding the _best_ fit polynomial?

Comment: There is a best fit polynomial: For $n$ given values, there is exactly one polynomial of degree $n-1$ fitting the values. Finding it is just solving a linear system of equations. It might be the case, however, that you don't really want a polynomial (a polynomial interpolation often gets weird near the end points) but for example a spline. You have to choose something, look e.g. on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Comment: The first one could have been $f(x)=2^x$ as another solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is, if you restrict yourself to for example "polynomials of degree $n$". Given how broad the function concept is, it is easy to see how ill-posed your question is. Just consider the class of functions $f(x) = 2$ for $x=1$, $f(x) = 4$ for $x=2$, $f(x) = y(x)$ for every other $x$. Every conceivable function $y(x)$ constructs an $f(x)$ that fulfils your criteria!

Even if you restrict yourself to continuous functions, there is in general infinitely many functional solutions to your constraints. In genereal however, for $n+1$ data points, a $n$ degree polynomial that interpolates the data points is uniquely given.

Comment: I see. However, is there a best solution to my context, simply the best solution, but not _the_ solution?

Comment: Yes --- but first, you have to give a precise definition of "best". That's most of the battle, working out exactly what it is that makes one solution better (for your particular purposes) than another.

Comment: @Michaelwm By "best", you probably mean "simplest". In that sense, most people would probably agree that the lowest possible degree polynomial is the "best".